# Apache Zeppelin (Shiro Security) cannot save note permissions

Tags: hadoop, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin.

I followed this tutorial on how to set authentication in Zeppelin and created two accounts. This is my shiro.ini conf file:

```
[users]
# List of users with their password allowed to access Zeppelin.
# To use a different strategy (LDAP / Database / ...) check the shiro doc at http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuratio$
admin = admin
joao = joao
#user2 = password3, role3
#user3 = password4, role2

# Sample LDAP configuration, for user Authentication, currently tested for single Realm
[main]
#activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.server.ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm
#activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=HW,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM
#activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword = Password1!
#activeDirectoryRealm.hadoopSecurityCredentialPath = jceks://user/zeppelin/zeppelin.jceks
#activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = CN=Users,DC=HW,DC=TEST,DC=COM
#activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://ad-nano.test.example.com:389
#activeDirectoryRealm.groupRolesMap = ""
#activeDirectoryRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = true

#ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
#ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldaphost:389
#ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = SIMPLE
#sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
# 86,400,000 milliseconds = 24 hour
#securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000
shiro.loginUrl = /api/login

[urls]
# anon means the access is anonymous.
# authcBasic means Basic Auth Security
# To enfore security, comment the line below and uncomment the next one
/api/version = authc
#/** = anon
/** = authc
```

I would like to set owner permissions in a notebook for admin user, however when I click save button nothing happens! Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Trying to save notebook permissions!]

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with:

```
[urls]
# anon means the access is anonymous.
# authcBasic means Basic Auth Security
# To enfore security, comment the line below and uncomment the next one
/api/version = anon
#/** = anon
/** = authcBasic

[roles]
admin = *
```

Comment: I think it could have worked with previous configuration as well, just by adding `admin = *` in roles

Comment: I've tried that but the /** = authcBasic config is essential

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `zeppelin.anonymous.allowed` property under `conf/zeppelin-site.xml` to false? That would be part of configuration to enable fully authenticated mode.

Comment: Hi! Yes I did put it to false

Comment: I see. So you're logged in as `admin` and changed the writes for all permissions to yourself. That means only yourself and the users with `admin` roles will be able to `read` or `write` your note. In order to confirm it, you could logout and login as different user (e.g. user2), then you shouldn't be able nether `read` nor `write` to note. If that doesn't help or confusing, maybe you could describe what you were expecting on saving permissions

Comment: I would like to restrict the writing permission to the admin user only.